# how to run a task in the background even if the app is closed with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, supabase, background-task

I'm using supabase for the backend of my flutter application, there is no cloud messaging for pushing notifications in the supabase and I need to notify the user when a new item is added .

So what I tried is to use the real-time feature of the supabase database for listening to the database changes and when the new item is added to the database I will notify the user using **flutter_local_notifications** package .

Now the problem is that I need to listen to the database changes even when the application is closed , I searched on the internet but I really did not get how these packages are work : **[flutter_background service](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_service)** , **[background_fetch](https://pub.dev/packages/background_fetch). **Any ideas about how can I achieve that ?

thanks for helping